# Ansible Playbook: Copy file with incrementing name

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

```yaml
---
- hosts: webserver
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: install web components
      apt: name={{item}} state=present update_cache=yes
      with_items:
        - apache2
    - name: copy apache virtual hosts config
      copy: src=demo/demo.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available mode=0755
      notify: restart apache2
```

I'm trying to, on copying `demo.conf` to the first host, rename as `demo1.conf` and on copying to second host it should be rename as `demo2.conf` and so on.

Or can it be renamed as `demo{hostname}.conf`?

What are some insights on this particular use case?

Comment: have you tested my solution?

Comment: Sorry I can't see any solution you have mentioned. But thanks I tried as @Peter Mortensen mentioned and its working. I'm setting up zookeeper clusters using ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your copy line like this:

```
copy: src=demo/demo.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/demo{{inventory_hostname}}.conf mode=0755
```

And you will have your destination file name linked with the name of the hostname.